# Accessing a property from an array of objects stored in state in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, properties, state

I'm working with ReactJS on a project and using KnexJS to access a database. I would like to store and use the JSON objects I retrieve, in the state of a component as something along the lines of the following.

`this.setState({tutors: tutors}) //Retrieval from database after promise`

and then access their properties like so

`this.state.tutors[0].email
this.state.tutors[0].firstname`

However, when I try this, I get the following error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined`

I have checked the console.log as well as using JSON.stringify to determine if the objects are retrieved by the time I need them. And it appears that they are. I simply cannot access their properties from state.

Is there something I can do about this? Or do I need to retrieve them from the DB one by one?

Comment: You may be accessing the data even before the promise is resolved, hard to say based on the current code that is provided

Answer (score 3):

This could be happening, because at the moment your code tries to retrieve data from state, the data is not there yet -- though it's possibly added later.  This is something that happens quite often, in my experience.  You should probably check that an object exists, before trying to access a property on it -- and return null or undefined in case it doesn't exist:

```
this.state.tutors[0] ? this.state.tutors[0].email : null
```

EDIT (in response to the additional code samples):

1. Assuming your fetch function works ok and adds the fetched data to state (I would use forEach instead of map to push the elements into the array, or just map over the fetched array and add that to the state directly, without an intermediary array/variable/push -- but I think your code should work)...
2. The problem has to do with the render method, since when the component renders initially the data is not yet in state, and as such you're passing an empty array to the TutorTable component, which probably in turn produces the error you see.
3. The data gets added to state later, but at this stage the error on the initial render has already happened.
4. You could solve this by rendering the TutorTable conditionally, only when the data gets added to the state:

```js
<div className="col-7">
  <h3> My Tutors </h3>
  {this.state.tutors.length > 0 && <TutorsTable tutors={this.state.tutors} />}
</div>
```

5. if you console.log out this.state.tutors in the render() method you should see in the console an empty array ([]) returned on the initial render, and then an array filled with data when the component re-renders when the data is added to the state.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Added this to the render function 
`console.log((this.state.tutors[0] ? this.state.tutors[0].email: null))`
The email property shows up just fine in the console... but it still is not found when I try to call it normally

Comment: Can you post the entire component?

Comment: There it is in full, I'm a n00b on here so I figured just post pics to be readable
https://i.imgur.com/GLfq7aO.png

https://i.imgur.com/Ek1DYh7.png

Comment: I think this is in the right direction, but I still can't access the properties immediately in TutorTable. Is there something similar I can do with them there? For some background info it's effectively a multi-page table that you flip though by pressing buttons, so I only display a few at a time. Here's the component: https://i.imgur.com/dfVJTYK.png https://i.imgur.com/5NaSicr.png https://i.imgur.com/jvpoX1y.png

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me you are trying to get the first element of an array `this.state.tutors[0].email`
is the tutors really an array,could provide the format of the data that you console logged as you stated.This probably should be in the comment section but I have less than 50 rep so i cant comment.

Answer (score 0):

you should check first tutors. if you are getting tutors an array then you can access its first element.

```
if(this.state.tutors[0]) {
   console.log("first element of tutors array", this.state.tutors[0].email)
   // anything you can acccess now of this element
}
```

and assign first tutors as an empty array in state.

```
state = {
    tutors: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in first lifecycle you have no data in this.state.tutors[0] 
for this reason first check this.state.tutors[0] is ready or not like this

```
if(this.state.tutors[0])
 {
   var data=this.state.tutors[0];
   data.push('your data');
   this.setState({tutors:data})
 }
```